# Get the scrolled position of an element whan scrolling up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing simple check how much the page scrolled to put an element on the page/hide it.For scrolling down everything works just fine,but whan going back it does nothing.Also have in mind that the first container on the page is 100vh,so i took it as reference whan to show/hide.my code is as follows:
HTML:

```
<div id="toTop"><a href="#">&uArr;</a></div>
```

CSS:

```
#toTop {
    position: fixed;
    right: 25px;
    bottom: 25px;
}
#toTop a {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #31ddb7;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var windowHeight = $(".testimonials").offset().top,
        lessHeight = windowHeight + 40;
    $(window).on('scroll',function(){
        var arrowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(arrowScroll >= windowHeight) {
            $("#toTop a").css("opacity", "1");
        }else if (arrowScroll <= lessHeight) {
            $("#toTop a").css("opacity", "0");
            console.log(windowHeight);
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Once again,distance to .testimonials from top is 100vh.
code goes to first if statement but not to the else if.I have also tryed with just if/else,but it whant work as well.

Comment: dont know what you are gonna do but if you really want to show and hide thats not with opacity, again telling if it is not your intention.

Comment: I know about that,will do it with scaling or display,its just that it whant enter second loop...

Answer (score 0):

Your code if working properly and in fact the statement goes in the else if. I'm not sure what the exact problem is you're asking help for.